# CakePHP: Can I delete error.log and debug.log?

Tags: cakephp

My application is already running live and cannot afford to be stopped.
I have found that the log file debug.log and error.log are about 1GB in size.
I have already corrected all errors possibles.
My question is can I simply delete the 2 files? 
Will Cakephp automatically create 2 new empty log files?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can delete them and CakePHP will recreate them if required (assuming webserver has proper write permissions to the directory).

You probably must be using a pretty old version of CakPHP as newer 2.x versions have log file [rotation](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6/lib/Cake/Log/Engine/FileLog.php#L77-L82) which avoids build up of such large files.